# set style to range in first row

Tags: c#, excel

How can we set style to all cells in a range? Rather than this code:

```
Excel.Range rangeCols =  xlWorkSheet.get_Range("a1", "CC1");
rangeCols.Orientation = 90;
```

What would be better to set style to whole row? Not limited to CC1. Helps wanted asap

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Excel.Range rangeCols =  xlWorkSheet.get_Range("1:1");
```

Comment: Thanks that worked . How can we manipulate the Cells in first column?